# Methods of Different Objects Not Able To Execute Simultaneously (D3.js)

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

New to javascript and I am experimenting with d3.js. I would like to create a website that visually compares different sorting algorithms. Basically, I modified sorting algorithms to have a 'displayArray' (a two-dimensional array that is a snapshot of each iteration of a sorting algorithm's loop). I then traverse that loop, and create a bar chart in d3 of each iteration The result looks similar to the famous [Sounds of Sorting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kPRA0W1kECg). However, I am having trouble running my animate function simultaneously. It seems that if two animations are going concurrently, they happen in the same div, as apposed to their own separate specified containers. I have already accomplished this using a [Frankenstein method of combining jQuery and D3](https://tylerjachetta.github.io/), but I am trying to use only D3 for the animations. Any help and suggestions are appreciated. Thank you!

```js
var w = 100;
var h = 100;
var barPadding = 0.2;

function graphObject(container, dataComp, algorithm) {
  _this = this;
  this.container = container;
  this.createDataSet = function() {
    var arry = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      arry[i] = i + 1;
    }
    if (dataComp == 'random') {
      shuffle(arry);
      return arry
    } else if (dataComp == 'reverse') {
      arry.reverse();
      return arry

    }
  };
  this.dataSet = this.createDataSet();
  this.createInitalGraph = function() {
    _this = this;
    var svg = d3.select(container)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', w + '%')
      .attr('height', h + '%');

    svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.dataSet)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return (i * (w / _this.dataSet.length)) + '%';
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return h - d * (100 / _this.dataSet.length) + '%';
      })
      .attr('width', (w / _this.dataSet.length - barPadding) + '%')
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d * (100 / _this.dataSet.length) + '%';
      })
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return '#ffffff';
      });
    svg.exit().remove();
  };

  this.animate = function() {
    _this = this
    frameArray = [];
    if (algorithm == 'bubbleSort') {
      frameArray = bubbleSort(this.dataSet);
    } else if (algorithm == 'selectionSort') {
      frameArray = selectionSort(this.dataSet);
    } else if (algorithm == 'cocktailSort') {
      frameArray = cocktailSort(this.dataSet);
    }
    for (var j = 1; j < frameArray.length; j++) {
      (function(j) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          _this.updateGraph(frameArray[j], frameArray[j - 1])
        }, j * 30);
      })(j);

    }
  };
  this.updateGraph = function(data, prevData) {
    var bars = d3.select(container)
      .select('svg')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(data);
    bars.enter()
      .append('rect');
    bars.attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return (i * (w / data.length)) + '%';
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return h - d * (100 / data.length) + '%';
      })
      .attr('width', (w / data.length - barPadding) + '%')
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d * (100 / data.length) + '%';
      })
      .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        if (data[i] != prevData[i]) {
          return 'red';
        } else {
          return 'white';
        }
      });
    bars.exit().remove();
  };
}

function bubbleSort(items) {
  var displayArray = [],
    swapped,
    temp;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      displayArray.push(items.slice());
      if (items[i] > items[i + 1]) {
        temp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[i + 1];
        items[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
  return displayArray;
}

function selectionSort(items) {
  var len = items.length,
    min,
    temp,
    displayArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    min = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      displayArray.push(items.slice());
      if (items[j] < items[min]) {
        min = j;
      }
    }
    if (i != min) {
      temp = items[i];
      items[i] = items[min];
      items[min] = temp;
    }
  }
  displayArray.push(items.slice());
  displayArray.push(items.slice());
  return displayArray;
}

function cocktailSort(items) {
  var swapped;
  var displayArray = [];
  var temp;
  do {
    for (var i = 0; i <= items.length - 2; i++) {
      displayArray.push(items.slice());
      if (items[i] > items[i + 1]) {
        temp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[i + 1];
        items[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
    if (!swapped) {
      break;
    }
    swapped = false;
    for (i = items.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      displayArray.push(items.slice());
      if (items[i] > items[i + 1]) {
        temp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[i + 1];
        items[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);

  return displayArray;
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}

var graph1 = new graphObject('.graphContainer1', 'random', 'bubbleSort');
var graph2 = new graphObject('.graphContainer2', 'random', 'selectionSort');
var graph3 = new graphObject('.graphContainer3', 'random', 'cocktailSort');

graph1.createInitalGraph();
graph2.createInitalGraph();
graph3.createInitalGraph();

$(".BubbleSort").click(function() {
  graph1.animate();
});

$(".SelectionSort").click(function() {
  graph2.animate();
  console.log(graph1.container);
});

$(".CocktailSort").click(function() {
  graph3.animate();
});
```

```css
html {
  background: black;
}

p {
  color: white;
}

.graph {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="BubbleSort">BubbleSort</button>
<button class="SelectionSort">Selection Sort</button>
<button class="CocktailSort">Cocktail Sort</button>
<p>Bubble Sort </p>
<div class="graph graphContainer1">
</div>
<p>Selection Sort </p>
<div class="graph graphContainer2">
</div>
<p>Cocktail Sort </p>
<div class="graph graphContainer3">
</div>
```

Bonus question: How would I accomplish this animation using window.requestAnimationFrame instead of setTimeOut?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `_this` and `frameArray` variables are global because they are currently assigned values without ever being declared with `var`. Use `var` to make them local.

Also, you don't need to define `_this` in each of your instance methods, because those methods are already within the scope of your `graphObject()` function and so can just use the `_this` defined on that function's first line.

```js
var w = 100;
var h = 100;
var barPadding = 0.2;

function graphObject(container, dataComp, algorithm) {
  var _this = this;      // <---- Add 'var' here
  this.container = container;
  this.createDataSet = function() {
    var arry = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
      arry[i] = i + 1;
    }
    if (dataComp == 'random') {
      shuffle(arry);
      return arry
    } else if (dataComp == 'reverse') {
      arry.reverse();
      return arry

    }
  };
  this.dataSet = this.createDataSet();
  this.createInitalGraph = function() {
    //  _this = this; <-- remove this line
    var svg = d3.select(container)
      .append('svg')
      .attr('width', w + '%')
      .attr('height', h + '%');

    svg.selectAll('rect')
      .data(this.dataSet)
      .enter()
      .append('rect')
      .attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return (i * (w / _this.dataSet.length)) + '%';
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return h - d * (100 / _this.dataSet.length) + '%';
      })
      .attr('width', (w / _this.dataSet.length - barPadding) + '%')
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d * (100 / _this.dataSet.length) + '%';
      })
      .attr('fill', function(d) {
        return '#ffffff';
      });
    svg.exit().remove();
  };

  this.animate = function() {
    //  _this = this; <-- remove this line
    var frameArray = [];      // <---- Add 'var' here
    if (algorithm == 'bubbleSort') {
      frameArray = bubbleSort(this.dataSet);
    } else if (algorithm == 'selectionSort') {
      frameArray = selectionSort(this.dataSet);
    } else if (algorithm == 'cocktailSort') {
      frameArray = cocktailSort(this.dataSet);
    }
    for (var j = 1; j < frameArray.length; j++) {
      (function(j) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          _this.updateGraph(frameArray[j], frameArray[j - 1])
        }, j * 30);
      })(j);

    }
  };
  this.updateGraph = function(data, prevData) {
    var bars = d3.select(container)
      .select('svg')
      .selectAll('rect')
      .data(data);
    bars.enter()
      .append('rect');
    bars.attr('x', function(d, i) {
        return (i * (w / data.length)) + '%';
      })
      .attr('y', function(d) {
        return h - d * (100 / data.length) + '%';
      })
      .attr('width', (w / data.length - barPadding) + '%')
      .attr('height', function(d) {
        return d * (100 / data.length) + '%';
      })
      .attr('fill', function(d, i) {
        if (data[i] != prevData[i]) {
          return 'red';
        } else {
          return 'white';
        }
      });
    bars.exit().remove();
  };
}

function bubbleSort(items) {
  var displayArray = [],
    swapped,
    temp;
  do {
    swapped = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      displayArray.push(items.slice());
      if (items[i] > items[i + 1]) {
        temp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[i + 1];
        items[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);
  return displayArray;
}

function selectionSort(items) {
  var len = items.length,
    min,
    temp,
    displayArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    min = i;
    for (j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
      displayArray.push(items.slice());
      if (items[j] < items[min]) {
        min = j;
      }
    }
    if (i != min) {
      temp = items[i];
      items[i] = items[min];
      items[min] = temp;
    }
  }
  displayArray.push(items.slice());
  displayArray.push(items.slice());
  return displayArray;
}

function cocktailSort(items) {
  var swapped;
  var displayArray = [];
  var temp;
  do {
    for (var i = 0; i <= items.length - 2; i++) {
      displayArray.push(items.slice());
      if (items[i] > items[i + 1]) {
        temp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[i + 1];
        items[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
    if (!swapped) {
      break;
    }
    swapped = false;
    for (i = items.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
      displayArray.push(items.slice());
      if (items[i] > items[i + 1]) {
        temp = items[i];
        items[i] = items[i + 1];
        items[i + 1] = temp;
        swapped = true;
      }
    }
  } while (swapped);

  return displayArray;
}

function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  return array;
}

var graph1 = new graphObject('.graphContainer1', 'random', 'bubbleSort');
var graph2 = new graphObject('.graphContainer2', 'random', 'selectionSort');
var graph3 = new graphObject('.graphContainer3', 'random', 'cocktailSort');

graph1.createInitalGraph();
graph2.createInitalGraph();
graph3.createInitalGraph();

$(".BubbleSort").click(function() {
  graph1.animate();
});

$(".SelectionSort").click(function() {
  graph2.animate();
  console.log(graph1.container);
});

$(".CocktailSort").click(function() {
  graph3.animate();
});
```

```css
html { background: black; }
p { color: white; }
.graph { width: 300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="BubbleSort">BubbleSort</button>
<button class="SelectionSort">Selection Sort</button>
<button class="CocktailSort">Cocktail Sort</button>
<p>Bubble Sort </p>
<div class="graph graphContainer1">
</div>
<p>Selection Sort </p>
<div class="graph graphContainer2">
</div>
<p>Cocktail Sort </p>
<div class="graph graphContainer3">
</div>
```